# Interpolation in a Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, interpolation

I'm trying to set a variable in a link.

```rb
<% @this.each do |this| %>
  <%= image_tag('www.somesite.com/#{this.name}.jpg') %>  
<% end %>
```

Basically there is an image identical to the name of the item, so i'm trying to call that in the link for the image.

But i'm missing something..

I found it works if i join them ->

```
<%= image_tag('www.somesite.com/' + "#{ctag.name}" '.jpg') %>
```

but i don't think that's a good practice ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation doesn't work if you put your string in single quotes. Double quotes should be used instead:

```
<%= image_tag("www.somesite.com/#{this.name}.jpg") %>
```

Comment: Wow, how quotes can change things... Thanks a lot